# Parse Server and Stripe Events

Tags: express, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-server

I am hosting my parse server on Heroku. Before migrating my parse.com account, I used the webhooks feature of parse to process billing events from Stripe using the URL http:KEY@api.parse.com/1/functions/stripEvents in strip's webhooks.

I have installed the node Stripe module as per the instructions of the migration steps.

My understanding is that api calls are no longer supported in the parse server platform. How would I route/send posts sent from Stripe to a function inside the new parse server platform?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "api calls are no longer supported".  The REST api works for parse-server.  I've never used stripe but if you need to set up stripe to call, say, a cloud code function just have it hit `www.your_app_name.herokuapp.com/parse/functions/yourFunctionName`.  You'll have to use the keys in the header but that will work in Parse.Server

Answer (score 1):

I stand corrected, it does work. 
www.your_app_name.herokuapp.com/path/functions/yourFunctionName is the URL to access a cloud function. You do however need to add the needed security keys. In the case of stripe you past this URL:

https://MASTER_KEY:javascript-key=JAVASCRIPT_KEY@your_app_name.herokuapp.com/v1/functions/FUNCTION_NAME

note that I mount my parse app on path V1.

Comment: so you only give stripe the url for the cloud code and add the master key and javascript key as in the url instead of headers like you would normally?

Comment: yes, I just double checked and that is how I am doing it. Is it not working for you?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but just doing some research before using back4app.com as my backend (it's a parse-server)